# Having trouble gathering correct user data and storing it into an array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

[this is my output and the numbers at the bottom should be the information the user entered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtvSU.png)I am trying to gather information from users and implement it into a struct with four variables that live within a struct and store it into an array that is within a class of mine. but when i try to print out the data, it gives me faulty numbers implying that it is either not collecting the data correctly or something is wrong with my display function. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

**This is my main**

```
int main() {
    Workoutarr a;
    int pushsize = 0;
cout << "this is a demo of making a progessive overload planner for a push day at the gym" << endl;

    pusharr(pushsize);

cout << "This is displaying the push array entered by the user : " << endl;
    display(a,pushsize);
```

**This is my cpp where all of my functions are housed**

```
void pusharr(int& c){
    Workoutarr push;
    char continu;
    string workoutName;
    int weight,set,rep;

        cout << "Would you like to add workouts to your push day routine : use Y/N" <<endl;
        cin >> continu; 
            for (int i = 0 ; continu == 'Y' || continu == 'y' ; i++){
                cout <<"What is the name of the workout you would like to add? : " <<endl;
                cin >> workoutName;
                push.pusharr[i].name = workoutName;
                cout <<"How much weight you you like to start the increment from :" << endl;
                cin >> push.pusharr[i].weight;
                push.pusharr[i].reps = 8;
                push.pusharr[i].sets = 3;
                c++;
                cout << "Would you like to contine ? : Y/N"  << endl;
                cin >> continu;
                }
    cout << "We have completed adding to the workout array." << endl;
}

void display(const Workoutarr &a,int c){
    for (int i = 0; i < c ; i++){
        cout << setw(20) << a.pusharr[i].name << setw(20) << a.pusharr[i].weight <<setw(20) <<  a.pusharr[i].sets << setw(20) << a.pusharr[i].reps << endl;
    }
}
```

**this is my header file**

```
struct workout {
string name;
int weight;
int sets;
int reps;
};
//type of workout
//what are there goals for working out

class Workoutarr{
    public:
        int displayCount = 0;
        workout pusharr [50];
};

//sets
void repCount();

void pusharr(int& c);

void display(Workoutarr a,int num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void pusharr(int& c){
    Workoutarr push;
```

This pushes input data to the local variable `push` that is destroyed after the function exit. You wanted something like you made for `display`

```
void pusharr(Workoutarr& push, int& c){
    // Workoutarr push;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and i made the changes that you suggested however I am still getting random numbers when I try to output the data.

Comment: I don't see any updates in your question.

Comment: It works well after my changes given in the answer https://ideone.com/9LjvUq